# Filtrar dados que não estão entre datas

Tags: sql, microsoft-access

Nós estamos fazendo um sistema de aluguel de caçamba para nosso tcc, porém na tela de vendas precisamos que apenas apareçam as caçambas disponíveis no período selecionado.

```
SELECT tabCacamba.CodCac, tabPrestadores.CodPre, tabregcac.dtini, tabregcac.dtfim
FROM tabPrestadores INNER JOIN (tabCacamba INNER JOIN tabregcac ON tabCacamba.CodCac = tabregcac.codcac
FROM tabPrestadores INNER JOIN (tabCacamba INNER JOIN tabregcac ON tabCacamba.CodCac = tabregcac.codcac) ON tabPrestadores.CodPre = tabCacamba.Prestador
WHERE (((tabCacamba.CodCac) Not In (Select tabCacamba.CodCac FROM tabCacamba WHERE [Initial Date] between tabRegCac.dtIni and tabRegCac.dtFim)));
```

Comment: Me parece que seu comando SQL está sintaticamente errado. Outra coisa é que você fala de disponibilidade no período mas apenas testa uma data de início.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito as regras que envolvem o seu problema.

Supondo que:

**01)** A Tabela de Registros de Caçamba armazena as caçambas e seus respectivos períodos em que as mesmas estão ocupadas.

**02)** A Tabela de Caçamba registra as informações da caçamba e do prestador associado a essa caçamba.

Uma possível solução seria:

```
SELECT tabelaCacamba.codigoCacamba, tabelaPrestadores.codigoPrestador, tabelaRegistroDeCacambas.dataInicio, tabelaRegistroCacambas.dataFim
FROM Cacamba tabelaCacamba 
INNER JOIN RegistroDeCacambas tabelaRegistroDeCacambas ON tabelaCacamba.codigoCacamba = tabelaRegistroDeCacambas.codigoCacamba
INNER JOIN Prestadores tabelaPrestadores ON tabelaPrestadores.codigoPrestador = tabelaCacamba.codigoPrestador
WHERE NOT(
    [dataInicialBusca] BEETWEEN tabelaRegistroCacambas.dataInicio and tabelaRegistroCacambas.dataFim
    OR [dataFinalBusca] BEETWEEN tabelaRegistroCacambas.dataInicio and tabelaRegistroCacambas.dataFim
);
```